# How does one order a relationship by a related model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider the following model definitions:

```
class Issue(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = Column(DateTime)

class Author(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Article(Base):
    [...]
    issue_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('issue.id'))
    issue = relationship('Issue')
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('author.id'))
    author = relationship('Author', backref=backref('articles', order_by=<???>))
```

I would like the `Author.articles` relationship (defined above as a backref on the `Article.author` relationship) to be ordered by the articles' `issue.timestamp`.

Is this possible?

**BONUS**: What if `Article` has multiple foreign keys to the `Issue` model?

Comment: Which queries did you try? Do you have a working example that returns the articles unsorted?

Comment: @AdamMatan To clarify, I am aware that I can order the results on the query itself after `join`ing with the related model; there is no problem there. This question was just about setting a *default* ordering using the `backref` function's `order_by` keyword argument, as shown in my example code above.

After scouring the docs and SO, I concluded that this is not supported.